# Can I give a python app/exe admin privileges just once after installation?

Tags: python, windows, admin, privileges

My program does changes to the host file, and it needs admin privileges every time it starts. The problem, is that I want it to start on computer startup, but I don't want it to ask admin privileges every single time.

My question is, how do I stop it to ask admin privileges every single time the program starts?

- Can I just ask for admin privileges a single time so that it doesn't repeatedly ask for permission?
- Is there a file in windows that can let me exempt an app/command that needs admin privileges?